# Errors during the execution of android application

Tags: java, android, android-activity, logcat, android-logcat

I am about to create my first android app 
:[This is a screenshot of how the app looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5lJl.png)

*So* The main idea of this app is to generate random numbers in the two buttons
and the user guess which number is bigger if he guessed it right:

This is the XML layout

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/app_name"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Press the button of the larger Number.if you get it right you will earn point !if you get it wrong you'll lose a point"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/left_button_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/right_button_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="0"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginBottom="57dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="points : "
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/score_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:text="0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reset_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Reset" />
```

This is the Java Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int leftNumber;
int rightNumber;
private OnClickListener ButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.left_button_number:
                if (rightNumber < leftNumber)
                    updateTheScore(1);
                else
                    updateTheScore(-1);
                break;
            case R.id.right_button_number:
                if (rightNumber > leftNumber)
                    updateTheScore(1);
                else
                    updateTheScore(-1);

                break;
            case R.id.reset_button:
                resetTheScore();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    numberGenerator();
    Button rightButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right_button_number);
    Button leftButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left_button_number);
    Button resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset_button);
    rightButton.setOnClickListener(ButtonClickListener);
    leftButton.setOnClickListener(ButtonClickListener);
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(ButtonClickListener);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

public void updateTheScore(int n) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_text_view);
    int score = Integer.parseInt(scoreView.getText().toString());
    score += n;
    scoreView.setText(score);
    numberGenerator();
}

public void resetTheScore() {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_text_view);
    scoreView.setText(0);
    numberGenerator();
}

public void numberGenerator() {
    int min = 1;
    int max = 100;
    Random r = new Random();
    leftNumber = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    rightNumber = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    displayMessageOnButton(leftNumber, rightNumber);
}

public void displayMessageOnButton(int left, int right) {
    Button rightButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right_button_number);
    Button leftButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left_button_number);
    rightButton.setText(right);
    leftButton.setText(left);
}
```

This is the logcat

```
 String resource ID #0x4a
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                      Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4a
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:266)
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3627)
                                                                         at com.example.android.big.MainActivity.displayMessageOnButton(MainActivity.java:87)
                                                                         at com.example.android.big.MainActivity.numberGenerator(MainActivity.java:81)
                                                                         at com.example.android.big.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: paste layout xml.. and also try to clean build project once more by deleting R.java if possible and re-run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void updateTheScore(int n) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_text_view);
    int score = Integer.parseInt(scoreView.getText().toString());
    score += n;
    scoreView.setText(score); // <---- this isn't working
    numberGenerator();
}
```

You passed an int as a parameter to your scroteView.setText(); . In this case, int is interpreted as a ressource ID (which is obvously not what you wanted).
A simple

```
scoreView.setText(score + "");
```

(implicit String cast) will fix it.

Answer (score 4):

```
public void numberGenerator() {
    int min = 1;
    int max = 100;
    Random r = new Random();
    leftNumber = r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    rightNumber = r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    displayMessageOnButton(leftNumber, rightNumber);
}
```

Can not set Integer to text

```
public void displayMessageOnButton(int left, int right) {
    Button rightButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right_button_number);
    Button leftButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left_button_number);
    rightButton.setText(right+"");
    leftButton.setText(left+"");
```

}